# Checking size of google maps cluster manager returns 0 then make same call again and returns a number

Tags: android, google-maps, for-loop, arraylist, android-maps-v2

So the problem I am having is I am trying to display a message saying "No Results found" if the Cluster manager is empty. But the first time the code is ran it returns 0 even when i can actively see markers on the map. I don't move the camera and make the exact same call and it returns the amount of markers. I clear the cluster manager at the  beginning to make sure it starts at 0 and then do a for loop to add the markers. Please Help! mItem = getMarkers() just gets an array of all the markers

```
 mItem = getMarkers();
                    mClusterManager.getClusterMarkerCollection().clear();
                    mClusterManager.clearItems();
                    for (int i = 0; i < mItem.size(); i++) {
                        float[] results = new float[1];
                        Location.distanceBetween(location.getLatitude(), location.getLongitude(), Double.parseDouble(mItem.get(i).getmLat()), Double.parseDouble(mItem.get(i).getmLong()), results);
                        float distanceInMeters = results[0];
                        boolean isoutside10km = distanceInMeters < 20000;
                        if (isoutside10km) {
                            mClusterManager.addItem(mItem.get(i));
                        }
                    }
                    int ammount = mClusterManager.getMarkerCollection().getMarkers().size();
                    int otherAmmount = mClusterManager.getClusterMarkerCollection().getMarkers().size();
                    Log.e("SIZE3", String.valueOf(mClusterManager.getMarkerCollection().getMarkers().size()));
                    if (ammount + otherAmmount == 0) {
                        Snackbar.make(navigationView, "No results found, try adjusting your filters", Snackbar.LENGTH_LONG)
                                .setAction("Refine", new View.OnClickListener() {
                                    @Override
                                    public void onClick(View v) {
                                        startActivity(new Intent(MapsActivity.this, Search.class));
                                        overridePendingTransition(R.anim.slide_in_right, R.anim.slide_out_left);
                                    }
                                })
                                .show();
                    }








 class OwnIconRendered extends DefaultClusterRenderer<MyItem> {

    public OwnIconRendered(Context context, GoogleMap map,
                           ClusterManager<MyItem> clusterManager) {
        super(context, map, clusterManager);
    }


    @Override
    protected void onBeforeClusterItemRendered(MyItem item, MarkerOptions markerOptions) {
        Bitmap bitmap = makeBitmap(MapsActivity.this, "$"+item.getmPriceHourly());
        markerOptions.icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(bitmap));
        super.onBeforeClusterItemRendered(item, markerOptions);
    }

}
public Bitmap makeBitmap(Context context, String text)
{
    Resources resources = context.getResources();
    float scale = resources.getDisplayMetrics().density;
    Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(resources, R.drawable.marker_bubble);
    bitmap = bitmap.copy(ARGB_8888, true);

    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
    Paint paint = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
    paint.setColor(Color.WHITE); // Text color
    paint.setTextSize(14 * scale); // Text size
    paint.setFakeBoldText(true);
    paint.setShadowLayer(1f, 0f, 1f, Color.WHITE); // Text shadow
    Rect bounds = new Rect();
    paint.getTextBounds(text, 0, text.length(), bounds);

    int x = (bitmap.getWidth() - bounds.width()) /2; // 10 for padding from right
    int y = (bitmap.getHeight())/2;
    canvas.drawText(text, x, y, paint);

    return  bitmap;
}
```

Comment: are you using custom markers and a class which extends `DefaultClusterRenderer<Object>`

Comment: @bharat yes there is I just edited the post to add the code

Comment: post this method `getMarkers();`

Comment: @bharat getMarkers() is from an api call class and also I should say that all this code is done in onPostExecute from an api call.

Comment: try this before adding any marker to map `mGoogleMap.clear();`

Answer (score 3):

If you want to marker size, you can resolve this

```
[ mClusterManager.getAlgorithm().getItems().size();]
```

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you *add* or *remove* item(s) from `ClusterManager` you need to call [clusterManager.cluster()](http://googlemaps.github.io/android-maps-utils/javadoc/com/google/maps/android/clustering/ClusterManager.html#cluster--) to refresh the items.

> public void cluster()
>    Force a re-cluster. You may want to call this after adding new item(s).

Comment: if           (isoutside10km) {
                                mClusterManager.addItem(mItem.get(i));
                                mClusterManager.cluster();
                            }

Comment: unfortunately, it is still being stubborn. Thank you for your input on re-clustering after I add or remove an item. @bharat